# only one instace of gtk applications allowed when compiler under windows msys2?

Tags: c++, dll, gtk, mingw-w64, msys2

I'm having the a problem when compiling under msys2 in windows environment:

I can using gcc to compile GTK+/gtkmm applications under msys2.  But when I execute the application compiled in this environment, then I can own open one gnome based gui at a time under windows.  when i try to opena second application it just focus the previous gtkmm application that I compiled.

And these are completly different GTKMM code bases used for generating the output exe.

I'm wondering.  is it possible to get more than on of these msys2/gtk compiled applications to run under windows at a time?

I'm thinking that maybe i need to copy the gtk dll's in the same path as the programs to make sure there are separate copies of these dll's whe starting each program.  Because currrently, I'm just adding the dll's to my path as C:/msys64/usr/bin and C:/msys64/mingw32 to allow the gtkmm application to find the gtk dll's.

Comment: This is the same application or different applications?

Comment: Different Application, but compiled with mingw64 under msys2 and sharing the same runtime dll's provided by msys2.

Comment: These are applications you wrote? You used the GtkApplication API? Do they have unique app ids?